# Как отключить все cookie в laravel8 до принятия пользовательского сограшения о использовании файлов cookie

Tags: cookie, laravel-8

Как отключить все  cookie в laravel8 до принятия пользовательского сограшения о использовании файлов cookie.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: При загрузке приложения появляются 2 файла cookies - _session и XSRF_TOKEN. Можно ли как-нибудь временно отключить эти файлы до определенного момента (например, до принятия пользователем соглашения о использовании файлов cookie)?